# Rendering React (scalajs-react) component with Diode error

Tags: scala, playframework, scala.js, scalajs-react, diode

I'm going to use Diode to manage application state with unidirectional data flow. I use Playframework 2.4 and Scala.js and here is a part of `build.sbt` for client subproject:

```
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    ...
    "me.chrons" %%% "diode" % "1.0.0",
    "me.chrons" %%% "diode-react" % "1.0.0",
    "com.github.japgolly.scalajs-react" %%% "core"  % "0.11.3",
    "com.github.japgolly.scalajs-react" %%% "extra" % "0.11.3"
  ),
```

I am able to run basic samples from scalajs-react and decided to extend [Timer sample](https://japgolly.github.io/scalajs-react/#examples/timer) with Diode support. I wrote a `Curcuit` object:

```
object TimerCircuit extends Circuit[TimerRootModel] with ReactConnector[TimerRootModel] {
  // initialModel and actionHanler implemented here
}
```

Tutorials and samples don't show us how to render React components using `ReactDOM.render(...)`, but only using package `japgolly.scalajs.react.extra.router`.

However, I don't want to use a router this time and want just to render my component into HTML root tag like this:

```
class ReactStateSampleView() {

  case class State(secondsElapsed: Long)

  class Backend($: BackendScope[ModelProxy[String], State]) {
    val DefaultInterval: Long = 1000

    //noinspection ScalaStyle
    var interval: js.UndefOr[js.timers.SetIntervalHandle] = js.undefined

    def tick: Callback = $.modState(s => State(s.secondsElapsed + 1))

    def start: Callback = Callback {
      interval = js.timers.setInterval(DefaultInterval)(tick.runNow())
    }

    def clear: Callback = Callback {
      interval foreach js.timers.clearInterval
      interval = js.undefined
    }

    def render(s: State): ReactTag =
      <.div("Seconds elapsed: ", s.secondsElapsed)
  }

  val timer = ReactComponentB[ModelProxy[String]]("Timer")
    .initialState(State(0))
    .renderBackend[Backend]
    .componentDidMount(_.backend.start)
    .componentWillMount(_.backend.clear)
    .build

  val sc = TimerCircuit.connect(_.data)

  ReactDOM.render(sc(p => timer(p)), dom.document.getElementById("timer"))
```

but this part

```
ReactDOM.render(sc(p => timer(p)), dom.document.getElementById("timer"))
```

doesn't work. Project doesn't compile and shows `"RuntimeException: There were linking errors"`

How to solve the problem?

## Update

Here is the exact message of the linking error and stack trace:

```
[info] Fast optimizing C:\tmp\project\client\target\scala-2.11\client-fastopt.js
[error] Referring to non-existent class japgolly.scalajs.react.Callback$ResultGuard$
[error]   called from diode.react.ReactConnector$$anonfun$wrap$1.apply(java.lang.Object)scala.Function0
[error]   called from diode.react.ReactConnector$$anonfun$wrap$1.apply(java.lang.Object)java.lang.Object
[error]   called from japgolly.scalajs.react.Internal$FnComposer$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(java.lang.Object)java.lang.Object
[error]   called from japgolly.scalajs.react.CompState$RootAccessor.modState(japgolly.scalajs.react.CompScope$CanSetState,scala.Function1,scala.Function0)scala.Unit
[error]   called from japgolly.scalajs.react.CompState$RootAccessor.modState(java.lang.Object,scala.Function1,scala.Function0)scala.Unit
[error]   called from japgolly.scalajs.react.CompState$WriteCallbackOps$class.modState(japgolly.scalajs.react.CompState$WriteCallbackOps,scala.Function1,scala.Function0)scala.Function0
[error]   called from japgolly.scalajs.react.CompState$ReadCallbackWriteCallback.modState(scala.Function1,scala.Function0)scala.Function0
[error]   called from org.example.client.playground.ReactStateSampleView$Backend.tick()scala.Function0
[error]   called from org.example.client.playground.ReactStateSampleView$Backend$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp()scala.Unit
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There were linking errors
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27) ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
    at org.scalajs.core.tools.linker.frontend.BaseLinker.linkInternal(BaseLinker.scala:133) ~[na:na]
    at org.scalajs.core.tools.linker.frontend.BaseLinker.linkInternal(BaseLinker.scala:86) ~[na:na]
    at org.scalajs.core.tools.linker.frontend.LinkerFrontend$$anonfun$4.apply(LinkerFrontend.scala:54) ~[na:na]
    at org.scalajs.core.tools.linker.frontend.LinkerFrontend$$anonfun$4.apply(LinkerFrontend.scala:54) ~[na:na]
    at org.scalajs.core.tools.logging.Logger$class.time(Logger.scala:28) ~[na:na]
    at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.Loggers$SbtLoggerWrapper.time(Loggers.scala:7) ~[na:na]
    at org.scalajs.core.tools.linker.frontend.LinkerFrontend.link(LinkerFrontend.scala:53) ~[na:na]
    at org.scalajs.core.tools.linker.Linker$$anonfun$link$1.apply$mcV$sp(Linker.scala:50) ~[na:na]
    at org.scalajs.core.tools.linker.Linker$$anonfun$link$1.apply(Linker.scala:49) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: What is the exact message of the linking error, and what stack traces are shown above? This information is crucial to identify which part of the code/dependencies is responsible.

Comment: @sjrd, I've updated the question. Stack trace points to `org.scalajs` only

Comment: I meant the stack traces *above* the "There were linking errors" message. That's what's interesting. It tells what could not be linked.

Comment: @sjrd, I've added more lines. The full stack trace is very long. Hopefuly, I showed the most important lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linking errors suggest that there is a binary incompatibility between scalajs-react and Diode. This sounds plausible from your `libraryDependencies`, because:

- You depend on `scalajs-react-core` 0.11.3, but
- You also depend on `diode` 1.0.0, [which depends on `scalajs-react-core` 0.11.1](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cme.chrons%7Cdiode-react_sjs0.6_2.11%7C1.0.0%7Cjar).

If there was a binary incompatible change in `scalajs-react-core` from 0.11.1 to 0.11.3, that would explain your issue.

If I am right, you can fix this issue by upgrading to Diode 1.1.0, [which uses `scalajs-react-core` 0.11.3](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cme.chrons%7Cdiode-react_sjs0.6_2.11%7C1.1.0%7Cjar).